# Sharepoint Newform Javascript variable scope

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, variable

I have a javascript in custom list newform looks this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var kontivalue = 0;

    function PreSaveAction(){
        belegnummer =  SPUtility.GetSPField('Belegnummer').GetValue();
        Netamount = SPUtility.GetSPField('Nettobetrag').GetValue();
        retrieveList().then(function(){
        var nettovalue = Nettobetrag;
        var totalamount = kontivalue + Netamount;
         });
        if(totalamount <= nettovalue){
           return true;
           $('.FormErrors').hide();
        }
        else{
           $('.FormErrors').show();
           return false;
        }
    }

    function retrieveList() {
       return getItems('InvoiceAccountAssignments').then(
           function(camlValue){
               var listItemEnumerator = camlValue.getEnumerator();
               while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                   var oListItem1 = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                   kontivalue = kontivalue + oListItem1.get_item('InvoiceAccountAssignmentsAmountN');
               }
           },
           function(sender, args) {
               alert('An error occured while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
           }
       );  
    }

    function getItems(listTitle) {
        var belegvalue = window.belegnummer;
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View Scope=\'RecursiveAll\'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'AttachedToInvoiceID\'/><Value Type=\'LookUp\'>'+ belegvalue +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'); 
        var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(items);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this,
                function () { deferred.resolve(items); }),
            Function.createDelegate(this,
                function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args);})
        );
        return deferred.promise();
     };
</script>
```

I changed my code according to the MdMazz.. comment below. i got one step further but the code works when i press the save button second time because the retrieveList() function is async. 
Thank you.

Comment: Anyone knows how can i do this. The answer from MdMazzotti is not working..

Answer (score 1):

I was tempted to comment about how awful your piece of code is (one over all: you are bloating the global scope with your variables), anyhow, the problem is that the function `retrieveList` is asynchronous, but within the `PreSaveAction` you are calling it as if it were synchronous.

You have to wait for it to complete, before moving to the next statement.

Make the following modifications:

```
//code omitted for brevity
Netamount = SPUtility.GetSPField('Nettobetrag').GetValue();
retrieveList().then(function(){
  var nettovalue = Nettobetrag;
  var totalamount = kontivalue + Netamount;
  // the rest of your code
});

function retrieveList() {
      return getItems('InvoiceAccountAssignments').then(
   // notice the added return statement before the getItems function invocation
   // the rest of your code
```

Now, that said, it won't work anyway. `PreSaveAction` is expected to return a boolean value synchronously, meaning that the caller won't wait on a promise.
You have to always return false, then do whatever you need to do and/or check, and finally manually trigger the form submit/postback.

Comment: Hi MdMazzotti, I am not good in javascript could you explain how can i do this which you explained above " You have to always return false, then do whatever you need to do and/or check, and finally manually trigger the form submit/postback." ?. Thank you.